# join multiple lines based on column1

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, join, merge

I have a file like below..

```
abc, 12345
def, text and nos    
ghi, something else   
jkl, words and numbers

abc, 56345   
def, text and nos   
ghi, something else 
jkl, words and numbers

abc, 15475  
def, text and nos 
ghi, something else
jkl, words and numbers

abc, 123345
def, text and nos
ghi, something else  
jkl, words and numbers
```

I want to convert (join)  it as:

```
abc, 12345, 56345, 15475, 123345
def, text and nos, text and nos,text and nos,text and nos
ghi, something else, something else, something else, something else   
jkl, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers
```

Comment: Do you actually have the extra blank lines in your input file? If not, please [edit] and remove them, you should show the file _exactly_ as it is.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind the order of output:

```
$ awk -F',' 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2};END{for(i in a)print i""a[i]}' file 
jkl, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers
abc, 12345, 56345, 15475, 123345
ghi, something else, something else, something else, something else
def, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos
```

**Explanation**

- `NF>1` meaning we only need to process for line which is not blank.
- We save all first field in the associative array `a`, with the key is the first field, the value is second field (or the rest of the line). If the key has already haved value, we concat two values.
- In `END` block, we loop through the associative array `a`, print all its keys with corresponding value.

Or using `perl` will keep the order:

```
$perl -F',' -anle 'next if /^$/;$h{$F[0]} = $h{$F[0]}.", ".$F[1];
    END{print $_,$h{$_},"\n" for sort keys %h}' file
abc, 12345, 56345, 15475, 123345

def, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos

ghi, something else, something else, something else, something else

jkl, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers
```

Comment: your perl solution from my question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124181/merge-2-rows-based-on-the-same-column-values should also work right?

Comment: No. The OP want to concat string based on column 1, regardless of duplicated or not. Your question doesn't want duplicated.

Comment: oh ok. At the first glance, it seemed like almost similar to my question. :)

Comment: Neat, +1! That doesn't _keep_ the order though, it only recreates it in this particular example where the fields are in alphabetical order.

Comment: Just for laughs, I'd written almost exactly the same approach before reading your answer: `perl -F, -lane 'next unless /./;push @{$k{$F[0]}}, ",@F[1..$#F]"; END{print "$_@{$k{$_}}" foreach keys(%k)}' file` :) Great minds think alike!

Comment: @terdon: lol, at first I also think to use push instead of concat string :). Yeap, Great minds think alike!

Comment: @terdon you don't need `..$#F` as there are no commmas in the second column. It's not clear if OP would want to keep them or not if they were. You'll also need to add `\n` to your print string, except for the final line, to match the desired output.

Comment: @Gnouc please explain your awk command little bit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Updated my answer!

Comment: @cuonglm Great answer, but could you please explain the `""` in the `END` block?

Comment: @Sparhawk it keep the key and its value as is, like `k, v`, using `print i, a[i]` will give you `k , v`

Comment: @cuonglm Ah okay, I was comparing to `print i a[i]` instead, which has the same output as `print i""a[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, that's an easy one. Here's a simple version that keeps the order of the keys as they appear in the file:

```
$ awk -F, '
    /.+/{
        if (!($1 in Val)) { Key[++i] = $1; }
        Val[$1] = Val[$1] "," $2; 
    }
    END{
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%s %s\n%s", Key[j], Val[Key[j]], (j == i) ? "" : "\n");       
        }                                    
    }' file.txt
```

Output should look like this:

```
abc, 12345, 56345, 15475, 123345

def, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos, text and nos

ghi, something else, something else, something else, something else

jkl, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers, words and numbers
```

If you don't mind having an extra blank line at the end, just replace the `printf` line with `printf("%s %s\n\n", Key[j], Val[Key[j]]);`